# Finding crosses and their orientation on a given image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to recognize table structure from some arbitrary photo image and store it in some formal notation (Let it be HTML table notation).

For example I have this blurry image as input:
[image]

After binarization I achieved this:
[image]

Now to detect structure I want to detect intersections between lines, their type (T-type, X-type, or simple corner), their orientations and their location on the image. After this I'm going to use all gained information for further joining of adjacent crosses in some structure, and translate this structure into formal representation.

The problem is in detecting crosses and their orientation:
[image]
[image]

In general these crosses may be scaled and/or rotated.
Maybe someone could help with method of solving this problem? Or maybe recommend different methods for this whole task?

That's what I have written so far:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 import cv2
 import cv
 import numpy

 original = cv2.imread("/home/user/my_photo-1.jpg")
 grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 smoothed = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale, (5,5), 0)
 cv2.imshow("original", original)
 cv2.imshow("grayscale", grayscale)

 binarized = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grayscale, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 8)
 binarized = cv2.Canny(grayscale, 50, 200)
 cv2.imshow("binarized", binarized)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks in advance for any response/idea.

Comment: If you are not sharing what you tried so far, maybe  [http://dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) it's a better place for your question.

Comment: i have made some modifications on [squares.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)
and get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xr18g.png). i know it is not a complete solution but maybe it will be a starting point to you.
you can find the modified code [here](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/blob/master/so36250677.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the Hough Transform. It will detect the different lines, and you will have the equations/orientations.

An other solution, maybe simpler is to:

1. Compute the skeleton
2. Strong pruning in order to delete all the small branches
3. Then, if a pixel has 3 neighbors it belongs to a T shape intersection, if it has 4, it's a cross intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried to use Hough Transform before, and I think it is not suitable for this task. You will get something like this after Hough Transform https://imgur.com/HGBjas4

1) It creates too many lines
2) Result will ignore merged columns/rows of table

Comment: It's certainly because you applied to Hough Transform to the image without computing the skeleton+pruning. Then the Hough transform finds lines on both sides of thick lines.

Comment: My second solution still works and I think that it is much easier.